# How to plot complex eigenvalues of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, complex, eigenvalues

I have a matrix , for instance, like this :

```
matrix[a_ ] := {{0, a}, {-a, 1}};
Eigenvalues[matrix[a]]
```

and this give the eigenvalues that depends on `a`

> {1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 a^2]), 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 a^2])}

If I plot this eigenvalues,

```
Plot[Eigenvalues[mat[a, b, q]], {a, -1 , 2}]
```

this just give me the real value. I would like to have the real part of the complex number too. How can I get the real part of the complex eigenvalue?

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`ReIm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html)  or [`Re`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html) or [`Im`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Im.html):

```
mat[a_] := {{0, a}, {-a, 1}};
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm @ Eigenvalues[mat[a]]], {a, -1, 2}, PlotLegends->"Expressions"]
```

[image]